# How to match a variable to a row in a dataframe and select the variable in a different column on the same row?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, grepl

I have a bunch of chat logs and have managed to pull email addresses from them and seperate the domains "@bacon.edu" I have a list of domains matched with a category name.

Basically I want to match the variable to a row in the column 2 pull the category name from column 1.

I should mention everything is **formatted as factors** currently but that can change.

In this example d1 = "bacon.edu" and name list is a data frame set up like this:

```
d1 = "bacon.edu"

Workplace Name  Email List
Pancake         @bac.edu
Test place      @toe.edu
superworld      @bacon.edu
monkey gym      @aclu.edu
toaster oven    @yoyo.edu
```

---

*The goal is to find bacon in row 3 create a variable from column 1 row 3(so abc = "superworld"), but i struggle to find the variable to begin with.*

I have tried:

```
which(d1, namelist$Email.List)
which(namelist$Email.List == d1)
which(grep
match(d1, namelist$Email.list)
which(grepl("bacon.edu, namelist$Email.List
```

Sadly I dont recall all errors or what they came from but they include:

```
integer(0)
object class not logical
level sets of factors are different.
```

I have sense deleted failed attempts. Im sure its simple and I feel bad asking but any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep`

```
namelist$1Workplace Name`[grep(d1, namelist$`Email List`)]
```